# Rails :before and :after elements

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have issue with :after and :before elements, appearing in my application. Each of these is 1px height and 0px width but it looks like white `< hr >`, whitespace, I mean.
Main part of **application.html.erb** looks like this:

```
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/search' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
    <%= value %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
```

`:after` and `:before` blocks appear after I rendered search partial. Have looked all through css and html files, can't find why they appear.

Comment: Can you post your search partial?

Comment: You should use the web inspector in latest version of Chrome, you can now select those pseudo elements and see where they're being defined in your css

Comment: This is my search partial <div class="SearchPlace"><input type="text"></div>

Comment: Are you sure they are in your source code? The Chrome inspector sometimes shows these, but if you view the page source you can see they don't actually exist in the source.

Comment: They do exist though. Any ideas why they can appear ?